# SUMPRODUCT and WEEKDAY ignore #VALUE error but keep values

Tags: excel

I really appreciate your help on this one.

I have a spreadsheet that we switch out every week with a new one.  But it keeps track of our numbers Monday through Friday.  The problem arises with a date column (column D), a invoice hours column (column N), and a cell that keeps track of hour totals by WEEKDAY.

The cell that keeps track of totals is where the #VALUE error arises (and I know why but I'll get to that).  The formula is such:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(D902:D978)=2)*N902:N978)
```

In this instance, it would be keeping track of the number for Monday.  It actually works fine, except I had an idea to automate the date in column D:

```
=IF(AND(B904<>"", D903=TODAY()-1), D903+1, IF(AND(B904<>"",D903<>TODAY()-1),D903,IF(B904="","","")))
```

(Column B is the name of the company for whom the numbers and hours are attributed).

As you may've guessed, it results in a #VALUE error because of the above formula in the blank cells in column D.  If I were to use SUMIFS it ignores the error, but I cannot get it to accommodate the WEEKDAY function.  SUMPRODUCT accomodates the WEEKDAY function, but I can't get it to keep the values but ignore the empty cells containing the formula.

Please let me know if I need to clarify in any way.

Comment: This is hard to follow, would you mind posting a picture of the worksheet range. It will make easier for you to get a fast and effective answer...

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to follow, but try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISERR(D902:D978)=FALSE)*(WEEKDAY(D902:D978)=2)*N902:N978)
```

Or this...

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISBLANK(D902:D978)=FALSE)*(WEEKDAY(D902:D978)=2)*N902:N978)
```

Comment: I know, I apologize for that.  The above formula still results in a #VALUE error.  I cannot understand why however.

Comment: Still the #value error, unfortunately.  I know that if I take out the automated date formula the sumproduct formula works fine, I just can't get it to work with that automated date formula in cells D903 - D978 (D902 contains simply the first date typed manually).

Comment: Can you post an image of column D that is representative of how it looks when the SP formula results in errors?

Comment: You'll probably laugh, but I don't know how to post images yet in comments. But I can describe it as the first cell in the column has the date, say 10-19-15. Every blank cell in the column after that has the formula: 

=IF(AND(B904<>"", D903=TODAY()-1), D903+1, IF(AND(B904<>"",D903<>TODAY()-1),D903,IF(B904="","","")))

 With the next cell down being 905, 906, etc.

Also, I don't yet know how to format these correctly.

Comment: @BenjaminHilton If you would not mind, could you just email the sheet? I'll get it working for you quickly. My email address is:  daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: @BenjaminHilton I'm still able to help if you can send me the file.

Answer (score 0):

An array formula will do what you are looking for.

your current formula would transform from a `SUMPRODUCT` to a `SUM` with an `IFERROR` formula

```
=SUM(IFERROR((WEEKDAY(D902:D978)=2)*N902:N978,0))
```

you will then need to enter it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

you will see `{}` appear around the formula when entered correctly.

Comment: OK.  I have now a value instead of the #VALUE error.  However, it is returning a 0.00 value, instead of summing the value in the cells N.  Right now, as a test, I have input 5.25 in three cells, N902, N903, and N904.  But the 0.00 is the value that is returned to me.  I am vexed.  Let me know if I can provide anything else to assist you.

Comment: it should only return a zero on errors. You may want to add the optional parameter to the weekday function so you can be sure that 2 is the weekday you are after

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't know what this means.  What optional parameter are you speaking of?  

I don't understand why the formula you provided doesn't simply ignore the errors in the blanks cells and leave the remaining values.

Comment: `=weekday(Date[,optional week start date])` - see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKDAY-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a) for more details

Comment: Here's an example using google sheets - functions are the same: [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iH0iJf0eiGnhI1SyPwy8EJ_rly-5pCvJSDWCr3Su0g8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The return type doesn't really factor in.  I did put it in but it had no effect.

If I take out the formulas in column D the sum formula works fine.  Put the formulas in and seemingly even the IFERROR option only returns 0 (if you put that as the value if false option).  Column N has formulas in the empty cells as well, but I don't see how that would matter.  But I bring it up all the same.